# Obtener datos de un dispositivo lector de biométricos

Tags: java, c#

quería saber si existe una manera estándar de acceder a la huella dactilar capturada por un dispositivo lector de biometría. Como ejemplo pongo esta analogía: Los dispositivos USB GPS sea cual sea al final capturan la trama de trafico sobre el puerto COM, entonces desde .net se puede acceder a esta trama y se obtiene información de georeferenciación. Lo que quiero es algo similar pero para biometría, sea cual sea el lector biométrico, capturar su información y procesarla, en resumen tal vez seria como un integrador de biométricos. alguien sabe algo al respecto o por lo menos una idea con la cual pueda partir?. Ya sea en .net o Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema es que los lectores biometricos requieren de librerias para poder accederlos, por lo general estos cuentan con un SDK el cual las incluye, segun el modelo podrias consultar con el fabricante del dispositivo, pero sino lo tiene podrias ver librerias genericas

[C# - Fingerprint Biometrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902266/c-sharp-fingerprint-biometrics)

como comente al menos tendrias que tener alguna libreria de uso libre

[Free Fingerprint Verification SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/free-fingerprint-verification-sdk.html)

[Biometric SDK](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biometricsdk/)